# My method is only returning one image when there are two images for the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a property entitiy. Each property can have multiple images.
I have a method that retrieves the property data, as well as the images, but only one image is being returned when I test the API in post man.

This is the interface

IPropertyRepository :

```
Task<Property> GetProperty(int id);
```

PropertyRepository :

```
public async Task<Property> GetProperty(int id)
{
   var property = await _context.Property.Include(ph => ph.Photos)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

   return property;
}
```

PropertyController :

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProperty")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProperty(int id)
{
    var property = await _repo.GetProperty(id);

    var propertyToReturn = _mapper.Map<PropertyForDetailedDto>(property);

    return Ok(property);
}
```

This is the class of the DataTransferObject that is used above.

```
public class PropertyForDetailedDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; 
    public int UserId {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas here?

AutoMapper

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<UserForRegisterDto, User>();
            CreateMap<PropertyForCreateDto, Property>();
            CreateMap<PropertyToReturnDto, Property>();
            CreateMap<PhotoForCreationDto, Photo>();
            CreateMap<PropertyToReturnDto, Property>();
        }
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is why you're only getting one image

Comment: @Andrew Would the first or default not return the first property that matches the ID?

Comment: @Andrew: No, `FirstOrDefaultAsync` applies to the `Property` set, not the related `Photo`s on that `Property`.

Comment: The only way you'd only get one `Photo` with this is if there is literally only one associated `Photo`. Check your data. Something is not right.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You're right, it must be something with the data

Comment: I've added my JSON reponse.

Comment: How is your `mapper` configured? Did you make sure `property` does indeed contain more than 1 entity in its `Photos` collection?

Comment: There is no obvious error in your code. If possible try to make a sql trace to see what sql is executed.

Comment: I have added the mapper class and a screenshot of the db

Comment: It doesn't seem like `PropertyForDetailedDto` is part of the registered mappings in your `AutoMapperProfiles`

Comment: `CreateMap` has the syntax `CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()` There is no definition where the "DestinationType" is  `PropertyForDetailedDto` so that would be needed for that type and its contained types

Comment: Apparently, `AutoMapper` can automatically map those properties even without explicit mapping. It's probably the `Property` itself that is being returned with a single `Photo` in it.

Comment: In order to see where is the problem, check each variable separately if contains what you expect. if `var property` does not contain the data, then the problem is with EF Core mapping, otherwise with AutoMapper or serialization. Since toy are returning `Photo` entity instances as part of the DTO, I  would expect it to be a serialization issue, but who knows.

Comment: Issue solved. I'll post a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.

In my PropertyForDetailedDto I had to include another DTO for the photos as opposed to a Model.

```
public ICollection<PhotosForDetailedDto> Photos { get; set;}


public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
```

Next, I had to map both the PropertyForDetailedDto and the above PhotoForDetailedDto

```
CreateMap<PropertyForDetailedDto, Property>();
CreateMap<Photo, PhotosForDetailedDto>();
```

I know the correct property as well as all corresponding that belong to property returned.